ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byte.buddy: Invalid module name: 'byte' is not a Java identifier"
This is the error am facing:

"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Selenium\WebDriver\byte-buddy-1.14.17-sources.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byte.buddy: Invalid
module name: 'byte' is not a Java identifier"

Can someone help me here?
Editor note to OP: TO DO add info here explaining what you're doing and how to reproduce it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You might have added selenium jar files under Modulepath. Try to add those jar files under Classpath and it will start working.

It seems like the module-info file is not discovered. That is surprising as it is included if you check the jar on Maven Central.
Did you build the library yourself?
